# PostgreSQL PAM authentication with Docker

Tags: postgresql, docker

I want to authenticate Linux host's users with the PostgreSQL database running in the docker container (If PG is installed natively, it works fine). I have a compose file like:

```
version: "3"

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: pg
    volumes:
      - /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd
      - /etc/shadow:/etc/shadow
      - /etc/pam.d/:/etc/pam.d/
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USERNAME: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
```

My `pg_hba.conf` file is:

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# PAM Authentication
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               pam
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     trust
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 trust
```

Under `/var/lib/postgresql/data` but I get the error when executing inside the container:

```
root@21cdb0e36245:/var/lib/postgresql/data# psql -h 127.0.0.1 -U testuser
Password for user testuser:
psql: error: FATAL:  PAM authentication failed for user "testuser"
```

Am I missing something in the volume mounts?

Comment: You should show the `pg_hba.conf` line and describe your PAM setup.

Comment: Okay updated the question

Comment: Looks like you didn't configure the PAM service `postgresql`.

Comment: I followed the same when working with native postgres installed and it works but Not working in docker.

Comment: Then you didn't configure PAM correctly in the docker container.

Comment: And how to do that?

Comment: https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/libs/pam/

Comment: I have visited the link but couldn't not find anything useful.